# var, sd, cor functions that have n as denominator

Tags: r, statistics, var, correlation, stdev

`var`, `sd`, `cor` functions in `{stats}` use `n-1` as a denominator (where `n` the number of observations). Out of curiosity, are there equivalent function that use `n` as a denominator?

Comment: maybe in some package somewhere, but I think people just generally multiply by the appropriate correction factor, or write their own utility function that does it .... http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/population-variance-and-sample-variance-td904148.html

Comment: Usually just multiply by `(n-1)/n` if I'm working with pop data. I think the answer might actually be just plain "no" here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(RH2) # needs Java
library(sqldf)

n <- length(BOD$demand)

sd(BOD$demand)
sqrt((n-1)/n) * sd(BOD$demand)
sqldf("select stddev_samp(demand) as samp, stddev_pop(demand) as pop from BOD")

var(BOD$demand)
(n-1)/n * var(BOD$demand)
sqldf("select var_samp(demand) as samp, var_pop(demand) as pop from BOD")
```